# Regarding object = new when another reference type points to it

Tags: c#, object, reference-type

I am vary curious regarding a specific case in c#:
In this code, `pointToSourceArr` points to source arr, but if I change `sourceArr` by a setting it to a new array or setting it to null, `pointToSourceArr` remains with it's two objects :
`{ "Itamar", "sasha" }`. Why is that?

```
string[] sourceArr = new string[] { "Itamar", "sasha" };
string[] pointToSourceArr = sourceArr;
sourceArr = new string[]() // OR NULL;
```

Comment: Please google about how references work in C# and you will understand the answer yourself

Answer (score 2):

> Why is that?

The value of each variable is just a reference to the array. The assignment here:

```
string[] pointToSourceArr = sourceArr;
```

*just* copies the existing value of `sourceArr` into `pointToSourceArr`. It doesn't set up a long-lasting relationship between the two variables.

Imagine I had a piece of paper with my home address written on it... and then I photocopy that piece of paper and give it to you. If I then cross out the address on *my* piece of paper, that doesn't change *your* piece of paper, does it? It's exactly the same here.

Note that if instead you'd change some data within the array, e.g.

```
sourceArr[0] = "Foo";
```

then that would be equivalent to me going to my house and painting the front door red - in which case if you then went to the address shown on your piece of paper, you *would* see a red front door. It's the difference between changing the value of a variable (no other variables are changed) and changing the value within an object (which means anything which can see that object can observe the change).

Comment: Does the house happen to be red?

Answer (score 2):

Because `pointToSourceArr` does not point to the variable `sourceArr` which is also a "pointer" (reference, in fact) but directly to this object `new string[] { "Itamar", "sasha" };` you created. And when you change where `sourceArr` variable points to, it does not affect where `pointToSourceArr` points to.

The following picture shows states before and after assigning null to the `sourceArr` variable.

[image]

Comment: To add the (almost) obvious: Since you still hold a reference to object the GC won't collect it.

Comment: @TaW Well, that's completely out of the scope for this question. The OP does not indicate any concerns about GC at all.

Comment: I'm sorry if you got the impression I was in any way critizizing your answer. But 'out of the scope of the question'? Not in my opion..

Comment: @TaW No, I didn't get that impression ;) My point is, if you bring GC while we're trying to explain him how reference types work, it's not exactly the first thing that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when your code executes it executes in order. So when you initialize `sourceArr` is has two values, `{"Itamar",sasha}`. Since your code executes in order, when you initialize `pointToSourceArr` and set it to e the same as `sourceArr` it becomes basically another version of `sourceArr`but still has the same values as `sourceArr` at this point. Now, once you change the values of `souceArr` since your code has already executed the first two lines it the `pointToSourceArr` is still going to be the same as it originally was all that is changed is the value of the `sourceArr.`

to explain this point more clearly, my name is Luke, imagine that I was named after my father, who was also called Luke. in code terms if would be fair to say `myName = fathersName`, now imagine that my father changed his name, my name would still be Luke, however his name would be something else.

Finally, if you want pointToSourceArr to be the same as SouceArr again, you need to once again write `pointToSourceArr = sourceArr;` after the value of `sourceArr` has changed.

Hope to have helped.

Comment: There are no 2 copies of the array. Just 2 references.